# AWS ObjectMetaData

Tags: vb.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I read this post: [Changing Meta data (last modified) on an S3 object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071399/changing-meta-data-last-modified-on-an-s3-object)

I am programming in VB.Net. When try to use this: 
    Dim iMetADatA As New ObjectMetadata

VS informs me that "ObjectMetadata" is not defined.

The class I am doing this in has all the AWS tools in the header

```
Imports Amazon
Imports Amazon.S3
Imports Amazon.S3.Model
Imports Amazon.S3.Transfer
```

I want to modify (i.e. "copy"/"replace") the meta data date and time after a file is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the datatypes specified in the official API spec here:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/N_Amazon_S3.htm.

Answer (score 0):

While uploading any object to s3 , no need to update the metadata (date and time etc), automatically framework will update, using GetObjectMetadataRequest() in java, like the same we can get updated object metadata.
 For more info please go through the following link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingNetSDK.html